# Eclipse Android Text View Text = String text

Tags: java, android, xml, string, text

I want the textView is a string, and the strin use in other XML data.

Is that possible? I can not!

The code does not work!

XML 1

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:text="">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/pt2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/pt4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:text="">
</TextView>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:text="@string/weiter"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
        </EditText>
                <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#000" android:inputType="">
    </EditText>
```

`

XML2

`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image1"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grid_item_image2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/onepic"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image2"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid_item_image1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid_item_image3"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/onepic"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image4"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid_item_image3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid_item_image1"
    android:src="@drawable/onepic"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image3"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/onepic"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,MissingPrefix" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grid_item_image4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid_item_image4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/grid_item_image4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:onClick="backmain"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid_item_image3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image3"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/no" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/no1" />
```

`

STRING

```
 `<resources><string name="no"></string>
  <string name="no1"></string>
```

`

JAVA

`public class Main extends Activity

`

I have a Texview the properties to be copied from the Texview to the other. is when you click on continue. But if the data are further clicks deleted.

Comment: i didnt got ur question

Comment: Your code should work. How does it fail? What is no1 equal?

Comment: @talkol no1 = string name

Comment: I don't understand. Please paste your XML file where you set the TextView text + your strings.xml where you have your string defined. And also say what the TextView shows on screen as its content

Comment: Make your question more clear.

Comment: Unable to understand anything from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save string in XML resources programmatically but only read them.

So, if I understand well your question, you must pass the value from the `TextView` you want to the `TextView` in xml2 (which I suppose is a different `Activity`) as an extra inside `Intent`.

That would be something like:

```
Intent goToXml2Intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
goToXml2Intent.putExtra("value", textViewYouWant.getText());
startActivity(goToXml2Intent);
```

How can you get this value on the Activity2's side? Easy...

Inside your `onCreate` method use something like to retrieve the previous value:

```
Bundle bundle = getExtras();
if(bundle!=null) {
    final String yourString = bundle.getString("value");
    yourNewTextView.setText(yourString);
}
```

Let me know about your progress ;)

Comment: I'm now probably something stupid. Can I send you my Java code?

Comment: @elHomer, Well, I don't know if I get your question, but yeah, show us the code.

Comment: my english is bad so I can not express myself well what I mean sry

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. I don't know why it is not working as *Talkol* said. But you can try in some different way.

In your values`string.xml` :

```
<string name="txt_value">This is a sample text</string>
```

In your layout`layout.xml`:

```
<TextView 
      android:id="@+id/resulttime"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/txt_value" />
```

And in your code:

```
String no1 = getResources().getString(R.string.txt_value);
```

Comment: it's will not work for me...